# WCF with windows auth and SSL

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, kerberos

I want to implement an WCF-Service that uses an TCP transport layer secured by TLS/SSL and still use windows authentication(kerberos/NTLM) on the server to identify the calling client. 
The part with the windows authentication already works but I'm not sure if the connection is encrypted.

I'm using a NetTcpBinding and create it like this:

```
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding()
        {
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),

            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),

            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,

            ReliableSession =
            {
                Enabled = true,
                InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
            },

            Security =
            {
                Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
                Transport =
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows,
                    ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign,
                    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12
                }
            }
        };
```

I already sniffed some packages with wireshark and found the following in one of the first packages: "application/negotiate".

I just want to be 110% sure the connection is encrypted with TLS but I'm not because i don't know how to check for it. 
Client certificates are not possible in my environment.

Please dont just paste a link to some microsoft-website on how to set things up.
There is no example that shows how to use both windows auth and TLS.
The application is **standalone**, so there is **no IIS** or something!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is example for Net.Tcp binding with transport security and standalone hosting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-windows-authentication

It has almost exact configuration as you do. The only exception is that you add reliable sessions (this does not affect security at all) and limit available SSL protocols to `Tls12` only (default value is `Ssl3 | Tls | Tls11 | Tls12`). So, it's still secure.

So, the answer is: yes, it is secured.